# where clause conundrum: where "LIKE" one thing but not "LIKE another" is failing?

Tags: mysql, substring, where-clause

hi I have a table structure thus:

```
mysql>DESC file;
file_id        
fullpathname
```

with records

```
file_id | fullpathname                                         
--------+------------------------------------------------------
      6 | /var/tmp/4x4 and 6x4/test/test3.txt
      7 | /var/tmp/4x4 and 6x4/test/somefile
      8 | /var/tmp/4x4 and 6x4/test          
      9 | /var/tmp/4x4 and 6x4/6x4_1.JPG     
     10 | /var/tmp/4x4 and 6x4/6x4_2.JPG     
     11 | /var/tmp/4x4 and 6x4/4x4_2.jpg     
     12 | /var/tmp/4x4 and 6x4/4x4_1.jpg     
     13 | /var/tmp/dir/4x4 and 6x4
```

and the query needs to be pretty much what I have below (but it's not working)

```
SELECT * FROM file
WHERE fullpathname LIKE '/var/tmp/4x4 and 6x4%'
AND fullpathname NOT LIKE '/var/tmp/4x4 and 6x4/%/'
```

but it needs to NOT return the file_id 6 and 7 it needs to only select "paths" one node deep. It's a weird one but this is the situation

what it should return is

```
file_id | fullpathname                                         
--------+------------------------------------------------------
      8 | /var/tmp/4x4 and 6x4/test          
      9 | /var/tmp/4x4 and 6x4/6x4_1.JPG     
     10 | /var/tmp/4x4 and 6x4/6x4_2.JPG     
     11 | /var/tmp/4x4 and 6x4/4x4_2.jpg     
     12 | /var/tmp/4x4 and 6x4/4x4_1.jpg     
     13 | /var/tmp/dir/4x4 and 6x4
```

Comment: `13 | /var/tmp/dir/4x4 and 6x4` won't be returned because it isn't `LIKE '/var/tmp/4x4 and 6x4%'`

Comment: no, that's ok that was an additional omission I forgot to identify, it's ok for my needs I didn't want `13` `6` or `7`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM file
WHERE fullpathname LIKE '/var/tmp/4x4 and 6x4%'
AND fullpathname NOT LIKE '/var/tmp/4x4 and 6x4/%/%'
```

Comment: yes you're right that works, of course, because of the subsequent string, of course